# How to add some padding at the top?

Tags: vim

My current vim setup sticks the first line all the way to the top, so that all the characters are touching the edge. Is there a way to to add a small amount of padding to the top so that the text doesn't touch the top?

Currently it looks as like:

[image]

Comment: I can't see what program you are using.

Comment: Maybe add a margin in the setup of your terminal.

Comment: I am using WSL2 with Ubuntu.

Comment: Not in Vim. Look up the documentation of your terminal emulator.